# How can I get past this error building Bookdown into ePub format?

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm getting an error building [R for Data Science](https://github.com/hadley/r4ds) in ePub format

```
> render_book("index.rmd", epub_book())
```

> output file: strings.knit.md
>
> Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting epub3 output.
>
> Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
>
> HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
>   your rmarkdown file:
>
> always_allow_html: true
>
> Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
>
> Execution halted
>
> Error in Rscript_render(f, render_args, render_meta, add1, add2) :
>
> Failed to compile strings.Rmd

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.8.0

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Is there something I can do to allow compilation to ePub that will keep all content intact?

Answer (score 0):

For my bookdown::gitbook project I deleted my _output.yml and _bookdon.yml files from the book directory and specified the sharing settings, documentation class etc in the Index.Rmd file.This solved it for my HTML output but I'm not sure whether the same applies for ePub formats.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problems, and (for me) narrowed it down to using `kable_styling` ([epub format with kable_styling fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915620/epub-format-with-kable-styling-fails))

No solution yet though... :-<

P.